# ui router query parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to learn how to use AngularJS UI Router in a small search app but can't seem to get the query parameters right.

In Chrome's address bar, it never changes from this:

```
http://localhost:8000/app/search?q=searchTerms
```

Instead of `http://localhost:8000/app/search?q=typeduserinput`

I have this for .config and .run:

```
    searchApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {


    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);/*for browser history, back and forward buttons*/

    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        //params: {'searchTerms': 'null'},
        templateUrl: 'home/home.html', controller: 'homeCtrl'})
      .state('search', {
        url: '/search?searchTerms',
        //url: '/search?q',
        params: {'q': 'searchTerms'},
        views: {
          '' : { templateUrl: 'search/search.html', controller: 'searchCtrl' }
          //add more views here when necessary
        }
      });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

}]);
  searchApp.run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope = $location;
  });
```

So my home page is real simple for now. Just a searchbox that provides autocomplete functionality.

I have this in my homeCtrl:

```
$scope.searchTerms = null;
$scope.searchTerms = $stateParams.searchTerms;
```

And my ng-submit button calls a search(), which has this code:

```
$location.path('/search').search({'q': 'searchTerms'});//chaining location, state and url parameters
```

Where am I going wrong trying to get the query parameters and ui router?

**UPDATE**
I've been doing lots of reading to better understand how UI Router fits into what I'm trying to do. I think I'm starting to "get it" now. My first mistake was that I have 2 controllers and both were loading ui.router as a dependency which seems to cause `Error: Could not resolve '/search' from state 'home'` because the the 'search' state has not been loaded yet -  and only 1 can declare ui.router as dependency - however, but both js files must be loaded.

So.... I think it makes sense to have homeCtrl (autocomplete) load ui.router and then have searchCtrl (searching) load homeCtrl... does that make sense, am I understanding this correctly? Would it make better practice to make a "routes" module that loads ui.router as a dependency as well and have homeCtrl load the routes module as a dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define `url: '/search?searchTerms',` it means that `search` state accepts query params named `searchTerms`.

Either change the name to `q` in the `state` definition:

```
url: '/search?q',
```

Or pass `searchTerms` as the query param in the `URL`:

```
http://localhost:8000/app/search?searchTerms=whateverYouWant
```

EDIT:

And of course, as @sid said, you should use `$state.go` to navigate between states and not `$location.path`.

```
$state.go('search', {q: 'searchTerms'});
```

Comment: it looks like I already had your suggestion in my code(comment), so I will just uncomment and comment the wrong line out, do I still need params {} ?

Comment: Not really, `params:` is for `non-url` parameters.

Comment: please take a look at my UPDATE and let me know if that is going in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to mix the ui.router paradigm with using $location.path directly. Why not use $state.go('search') instead. Read this:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options

AND THIS

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23455158/559095

Also, your passing of searchParams between states doesn't look correct. Go through the following links to understand this better. You may need a resolve property in your search state:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28248244/559095
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23455158/559095

Comment: yea it seems I was, and did not even realize it. Still learning Angular... let me try go over this again and I will let you know how I make out, thanks for your efforts!

Comment: so it seems if I'm using UI Router, I don't really need $location service at all, is that correct?

Comment: Correct, there should be no need of $location service for this purpose.

Comment: Take a look at this GitHub code https://github.com/sidazad/angularjstutor for the site http://angularjstutor.com/coursedes
This should help you

Comment: please take a look at my UPDATE and let me know if that is going in the right direction?

Comment: @user3125823 ui router should be loaded as a dependency of the top level module and not of any individual controller. You can load it where you are calling angular.module.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108314/discussion-between-user3125823-and-sid).

Comment: @user3125823 Maybe go through this example: https://github.com/sidazad/angularjstutor/blob/master/static/app/js/app.js